# Jmeter Groovy webdriver By.xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter+Groovy and want to wait for the element to display in an UI, but it is failing with this error:

> 2020-10-06 16:02:03,775 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: By for class: Script42

My code is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); 
WDS.browser.get('https://google.com/');
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 2):

Add import for missing class(es) at start of the script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```